# Can't Run Tests in Force.com IDE

Tags: force.com-ide

I just got a new work pc and I got all my software reinstalled.  The version of eclipse that our company uses is compatible with only up to version 36 of the Force.com IDE, so I can't use 37 at this moment.

The problem though is whenever I try to run a test from version 36 (using the new run configurations method), after I click on the run button, the loading bar shows up for a sec and it looks like it's doing something, but nothing really happens.  The screen just flashes but the test didn't actually run.  The Apex Test Runner tab is still blank, and on the server side I'm not seeing any requests to run the test.

I started reverting back to older versions to see if I could find one that works:
-  Version 35 just gave me this "Try running the test again if that doesn't work, run the test from Apex Test Execution in Setup or from the Developer Console" error
- Version 34 has the same issue as version 36
- Version 33 has the old right click -> run tests method.  This one works, I can see the test request on the server, and the Apex Test Runner tab is populated with the test results

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong or some setting that I maybe need to flip?  Thanks

Comment: In the [run configuration](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/runTests.htm), are you selecting specific classes, methods, or test suites? Are any of the classes you are testing on v37.0 or v38.0?

Comment: You might find it useful to enable the [debug mode](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/ide_pro_eclipse_logging.htm) and then check the corresponding log file.
If all else fails, create an [issue on the GitHub project](https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/issues).